# TypeORM Cascade Delete

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

Am having troubles deleting my entities, i have the following partial codes

```
@ManyToOne(type => Comment, comment => comment.replies, {
    onDelete: "CASCADE"
})
parent: Comment;
```

and

```
@OneToMany(type => Comment, comment => comment.parent)
replies: Comment[];
```

I have tried `manager.remove(comment)` and

```
await manager
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .delete()
    .from(Comment)
    .where("id = :id", { id: comment.id })
    .execute();
```

Both don't work, is there something am doing wrong, how do I go about this, here is my select query

```
let comment = await manager
    .createQueryBuilder(Comment, "comment")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("comment.user", "user")
    .where("comment.id = :id", { id: request.body.comment })
    .getOne();
```

The error am getting is

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED_2: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even though the question is not so well-phrased, the code examples you added and the fact it eventually worked, helped me to figure out how to configure cascading operations properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Apparently i had to delete all tables and do a fresh migration for the `onDelete: "CASCADE"` to take effect but worked

Answer (score 4):

next time, change property "onDelete" in your models, and create a migration to change it on your database.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have the following decorator in an entity.

```js
  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;
```

If you have this decorator and then have is turned on in a service. You'll see that it respects the deletedAt time and doesn't actually remove it from the db, but instead the services will automatically not return it if respecting the flag.

```js
{ useSoftDelete: true })
```

Next I would check what is actually set in the database. If you are using synchronize true then it might reflect correctly, but you should use a migration to create everything for production purposes or risk data loss.

Cheers and good luck mate!