# drop table cascade doesn't remove all of the references of that table

Tags: mysql, postgresql, typeorm

when I run `DROP TABLE 'User' cascade;` it doesn't remove records from other tables that have reference to User.

If I run `DELETE FROM 'User'` it successfully removes records from other tables too. How can I do this from DROP TABLE? this is very important.

btw if I run `DROP TABLE 'User'` without cascade it tells me that other tables depend on this so please add cascade;

Comment: I assume you mean `DELETE FROM`, not `REMOVE FROM`. What's wrong with first doing `DELETE FROM` and then doing `DROP TABLE`?

Comment: Yes, good call I mean DELETE from, well client doesn't want to do it this way and I'm really interested why DROP cascade doesn't work the way it's intended too :/

Comment: I'm going to guess you don't have ```ON DELETE CASCADE``` on the ```FOREIGN KEYs``` in the child table(s).

Comment: of course I have, I use TypeOrm NestJS I tried {cascade: true} and onDelete: 'CASCADE' in the child table(s) which have OneToOne and OneToMany/ManyToOne relationships, But when I DROP table it doesn't remove it's childs

Comment: Yes but do the actual database tables have it set up. Also checkout [Issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1460)"guys, typeorm doesn't remove anything by cascades on its own. The only thing it does is it sets onDelete: "CASCADE". The actually removal is database responsibility, so please make sure you got it right how onDelete in your database works.". [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363308/typeorm-cascade-delete)"Apparently i had to delete all tables and do a fresh migration for the onDelete: "CASCADE" to take effect but worked". So Typeorm has some flaky behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a foreign key constraint pointing to a table, and you drop that table with `CASCADE`, the foreign key constraint will be dropped, so the result is consistent, but not what you want.

If you want a cascading delete, you could simply delete all rows where the foreign key is not NULL:

```
DELETE FROM child
WHERE fk_col IS NOT NULL;
```

If the column is `NOT NULL`, a `TRUNCATE` would be faster.